# Указатели. Найти минимальное число

Tags: c++

```
    int main()
{
    int a = 8;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 1;

    int dob = 0;
    int* pdob = &dob;

    int avg = 0;
    int* pavg = &avg;

    int min = 0;
    int* pmin = &min;



    int* pa = &a;
    int* pb = &b;
    int* pc = &c;

    *pdob = (*pa) * (*pb) * (*pc);
    cout <<"dob -> "<< *pdob << endl;

    *pavg = *pa + *pb + *pc / 2;
    cout <<"average -> "<< *pavg << endl;

    if (*pb < min)
    {
        min = *pb;
    }

    if (*pc < min)
    {
        min = *pc;
    }

    cout <<"min -> "<< *pmin << endl;

}
```

не могу понять почему 0 - в минимальном, что может быть здесь не правильно.

Comment: Ну потому что вы в самом начале туда ноль записали.

Comment: П.С. Среднее у вас вообще ни разу не среднее, а фигня на палочке

Comment: а как правильно?

Comment: *pavg = (*pa + *pb + *pc) / 3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых среднее надо считать так:
`*pavg = (*pa + *pb + *pc) / 3.0;`.

Во-вторых присвойте минимуму какое-то из начальных значений
`min = a`, например.

Comment: среднее исправил

Comment: @that_drowning_man а минимум?

Comment: тоже исправил, там должно быть int min = a;
а было 0